# Which part of Hazelcast is free?

Tags: hazelcast

I want to use Hazelcast in one of my projects (proprietary, commercial product). I'm having troubles with understanding Hazelcast license and pricing model. Which parts of it a can use free of charge?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Hazelcast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the chart referenced below, everything in orange is part of the Open Source (free) product.   The legend to the chart labels this as professional support, indicating there is support available for purchase for all of the open source portion of Hazelcast IMDG, but it is all free to use.

EDIT: I can no longer find the referenced chart on the website, but it is on the first page of this datasheet:  https://hazelcast.com/resources/hazelcast-product-datasheet/

Essentially, just about everything a developer needs to build working software is open-source; the enterprise version adds things that a DevOps engineer may want to have for production deployments - disaster recovery (via WAN Replication), SSL encryption, Rolling Upgrades and Blue-Green deployments to eliminate downtime when upgrading software, etc.

Comment: Updated one link, and put some of the info in-line so it's not necessary to chase down the document unless you just want further info.

Answer (score 1):

i was asking me same question as you. I found this information at the new website:

[Products Feature Comparison](https://hazelcast.com/products/feature-comparison/)

Also if you go to the [documentation site](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/overview/architecture) you will get the datasheet that Mike Yawn is referencing, i guess. Important is to filter the documentation with the category for the version of IMDG.

There are also in some Enterprise Features like [WAN](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/wan/wan) bold text alerting you that feaute is for enterprise/pro and so on.

Answer (score -1):

See this for details on free and commercial features: https://hazelcast.com/pricing/